# Determine whether an array contains a value and update or create it

Tags: javascript, logic

So i have this Cart object in Javascript... What i want to do is check if an item is present in the given cart.

- If present, update its amount.
- If not, push it to the items array.

I've done it this way

```
let item = {id: this.id, name: this.name, price: this.price, amount: this.amount}
let hasItem = false;

this.cart.items.forEach(element => {
    if (element.id === item.id) {
        element.amount += item.amount
        hasItem = true; 
    }
})
if (!hasItem) {
    this.cart.items.push(item);
}
```

It works fine, but i was wondering if there is a faster, more effective way of doing this... What would you suggest?

Comment: If you know that there's only one item with that id, you could skip the rest after having found it. Have a look at the `findMethod`. But no, you can't get more efficient with an array (unless you keep it sorted).

Comment: @Archer Uh, no?

Comment: This one: [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: @georg Why `Map`?

Comment: @klferreira: posted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more efficient way would be to use a proper data structure ([`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)) instead of the array, for example:

```js
let basket = new Map();

function add(product) {
    if(basket.has(product.id))
        basket.get(product.id).amount += product.amount;
    else
        basket.set(product.id, {...product});
}

add({id:1, name: 'bread', amount:1});
add({id:2, name: 'butter', amount:2});
add({id:1, name: 'bread', amount:2});
add({id:1, name: 'bread', amount:1});

console.log([...basket.values()])
```

This way, you have guaranteed O(1) lookup by the product id.

Comment: Very interesting. I've always used arrays for this type of task and it just doesnt feel like the right way... Will definitely try `Map`!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method. The biggest advantage is that if the item is found in the array, it doesn't traverse the array further (which [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) does, and you can't stop it from doing so).

```
let item = {id: this.id, name: this.name, price: this.price, amount: this.amount};
let listItem = this.cart.items.find(element => element.id === item.id)

if (!listItem) {
    this.cart.items.push(item);
} else {
    listItem.amount += item.amount;
}
```

Comment: I did not know that when i update the object returned by find, the changes would reflect in the equivalent item in the array. Thanks!!!

Comment: @klferreira -- Because JS returns the reference to the item, you can modify it in place.

Answer (score -1):

Try it

```
let item = { id: this.id, name: this.name, price: this.price, amount: this.amount };

typeof ( this.cart.items.find( a => { return a.id === item.id ? ( a.amount += item.amount, true ) : false; } ) ) !== 'object' ? this.cart.items.push( item ) : undefined;
```

Comment: How does this fulfill the requirement of TO (@kiferreira)? O.o If there's an item with the same id (which is only used to get its "type") a new item will be pushed into the array/cart. Otherwise nothing is done. And all this with a misused ternary operator...

Comment: typeof ( this.cart.items.find( a => {
      return a.id === item.id ? ( a.amount += item.amount, true ) : false;
     } ) ) !== 'object' ? this.cart.items.push( item ) : undefined;

Comment: why you think this is misused of ternary operator ? I'm not clear. Please explain me. I like to know from you @Andreas